# Bootstrap not working on Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

My rails app is styled with Bootstrap delivered from a CDN. It works fine in development but the styling is lost after uploading to Heroku. I don't have any bootstrap gems in the gemfile. Here is a screen shot of my appplication.html.erb file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= page_title %></title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<%= render "layouts/header" %>
<%= flash[:notice] %>
<%= flash[:alert] %>
<div id="main">
<%= render "layouts/left_sidebar" %>
<div id="body"><%= yield %></div>
<%= render "layouts/right_sidebar" %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure about the info inside the head tags, maybe it is incorrect or should I add a gem? I am not sure what to do. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that in one of your cdn call is http and not https trye adding that s if that does not work you should add the gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's causing the problem, but the protocol for one of your Bootstrap links is http and the other is https. You might check your console for load errors.

Since you mentioned the gem, adding this to your Gemfile should do the trick:

```
gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', '~> 3.0.0.3', :require => 'bootstrap-rails'
```

I have three apps on Heroku running Bootstrap with this gem and it has never given me any trouble.

Comment: Yes, the missing 's' was part of the problem. I now have a bootstrap carousel that is not working. I will create another post. Thanks.

Comment: I'll save you the trouble. Just add this to app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require twitter/bootstrap - if you're using the gem

Comment: Also, you have to fix the 's' for your stylesheet link(s) as well as your script link(s). I see you had the same issue with http/https on the script tags: <script src="https://ajax.goog..., <script src="http://maxcdn..... Make sure you fix those

Comment: Yes, I only fixed one of the typos. Did not see the second one. All is working now. Thanks again.